# How can I pipe bytes from a reader to a writer with an interceptor?

Tags: io, rust

How can I perform something like `std::io::copy(&mut from, &mut to);`, but with an interceptor in the middle? So that I can, for instance, perform a SHA-256 hash of the whole stream?

Answer (score 2):

It is common and good practice for byte stream hashers and other raw streamed processors to implement `Write`, through which the stream can be fed into the process (see e.g. [the `Hasher` type from `crypto_hash`](https://docs.rs/crypto-hash/0.3.4/crypto_hash/struct.Hasher.html)).

Therefore, a solution to data stream interception would be (1.) ensuring that the processor indeed implements `Write`, (2.) making a writer type that replicates the writing process to two independent writers at once. I found at least one crate providing this mechanism ([`broadcast`](https://crates.io/crates/broadcast)), but implementing this by hand should not be overly complex.

With this available, a new function signature for an intercepted copy can be derived.

```rust
fn copy_intercept<I: ?Sized, O: ?Sized, M: ?Sized>(
    input: &mut I,
    output: &mut O,
    intercept: &mut M,
) -> std::io::Result<u64>
where
    I: Read,
    O: Write,
    M: Write,
{
    std::io::copy(input, &mut BroadcastWriter::new(output, intercept))
}
```

Comment: If the interceptor is your own, you will just have to implement `Write` for it.